# Understanding while loops in "Intro to Python"

Tags: python-3.x

I've got the following exercise:

```
x = 1
i = 0
while i < 4:
    x = x * 2
    i += 1
print(x)
```

Can you please explain the procedure of this result?
Why it prints only 16?

Comment: when i is 4 the loop is not executed

Comment: The loop runs for each of 0,1,2,3 as a value of i. So, a total of four times only.  1*2, 2*2, 4*2, 8*2. If you are just starting with programming/python, you may try http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit, paste your code into the input box and click `visualize execution`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop runs for 4 times as you are starting with i=0 and in each iteration you are adding one to i. Now in each iteration you are multiplying x with 2 so in the end it will be 1*2*2*2*2 and hence it is printing 16.

Comment: a=5
b=8
r=0
while a>0:
    r=r+b
    a=a-1
print(r) - why it prints 40?

Comment: because a is 5 so the loop will run 5 times and in each iteration, you are adding 8 in the r so 8+8+8+8+8 = 40

Answer (score 0):

Here,initially:

```
x = 1
i = 0
```

Now till `i = 4` (the condition of the `while` loop), the `while` loop is excecuted. In every loop, `x` is incremented by `x * 2`. As `i` is incremented one by one, the loop runs for 4 times( `i` has to reach 4 so that the loop is done). Therefore,

```
x = (((1*2)*2)*2)*2 = 16
```